# Moltres disappeared completely

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I chased moltres around about 7 times, but when I saved and logged back on, he is gone - from the map, and the sea spirit's den. I redid the elite four, with hopes it would reset, but that did not seem to work. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. One of those *facepalm* moments. You have to check the pokèdex, not the map.